# Want to record text of textbox in QTP , Object id of this textbox is dynamic

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I want to get textbox's object ID which is dynamic 
Application is windows application developed in c#.net

how to record and get object ID using QTP??

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you want to obtain the object ID (which? The window handle?), then it is a totally different story if you want to recognize an object having just variable object "ids"(i.e. properties) from run to run.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight answer to your question unless one personally analyzes the scenario, however below are some solutions which may be applicable.

1. Try to identify any unique property of the object other than one, which qtp recognizes while recording and do descriptive programming. (In your case if object ID is a number then go for some text describing the textbox).
2. If this is not possible do descriptive programming with regular expression matching all the property value that the object have.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

identify unique property of the object, which qtp recognizes while recording and do programming.If not possible do with regular expression matching all the property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Reconfigure your object identification configuration so QTP uses different identification properties (see documentation).

Option 2: Use descriptive programming to address the control using an appropriate (unique) combination of attributes (see documentation).

Use option 1 if the control type always needs nonstandard handling in terms of identification. Use option 2 for exceptions.